# What is the difference between modifying 'Indexing Option' and 'Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties'

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-search, search-indexing

[This article explains how to turn off the index(Link).](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/simple-ways-to-increase-your-computers-performace-turn-off-indexing-on-your-local-drives/) I'm not interested in turning off the index, but I'm curious about 2 different options.

In "Turn Off Indexing Selectively" section from the article, they turn it off by modifying `Indexing Options`. In "Turn Off Indexing for a Drive" section, they turn off `Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties`. I wonder if those settings behave differently.

For example, If I added a path "C:\Foo" from `Indexing Options` but turned off `Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties` from the folder properties, is the folder indexed? If so, what is `Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties for"?

Note that Contents is not the same as Properties.

> This tells the system that when it indexes the file, it should also index the contents of the file.
>
> Indexing the contents of a file allows you to use the Search feature of Windows Explorer to find files that contain the specified text. If the contents are not indexed, the Search feature will only find files by their name.

Source [Understanding and Using File Attributes (Tips.Net)](https://windows.tips.net/T012023_Understanding_and_Using_File_Attributes.html)

Comment: Thank you. It seems "Turn Off Indexing for a Drive" from the article was wrong then.

Comment: @user2652379 Not really, as it didn't mention what it does and was in a section about turning indexing completely off.